# Creation of my_smart_contract pending in Remix

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, remix

I have been trying to deploy my first contract on Remix using Ropsten Network with metamask but i am always seeing this
Creation of my_smart_contract pending

Please how can i resolve this

Comment: Did you confirm the (deploying) transaction in your MetaMask? What gas price did you use? Can you link the pending transaction (e.g. Etherscan)?

Comment: It never prompted anything on metamask, immediately I clicked deploy it starts showing "creation of  my_smart_contract pending" in the console. I also used 3 gwei, I can't link it Etherscan

Comment: Ok. I was assuming you're using MetaMask because of the tag in the question. So what have you selected in the Evironment box in the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab? Is your intention to submit the transaction from MetaMask (even though it's not opening) or do you hold the private key to the deployer address elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I am using metamask, I selected the injected Web3 environment, then connect my remix to metamask so that it will capture my address (account) in metamask before I clicked deploy in remix but it still shows creation pending without prompting anything in metamask

Comment: So far everything seems fine according to your description. My guess is that your browser is blocking the pop-up window from MetaMask. Check your browser settings and try to temporarily allow all pop-ups. However issues like this are really hard to reproduce, so I don't have a better answer. Hope this helps at least.

Comment: I've tried it, still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the error will because of EIther you haven't changed  the deployed option to web3 provider or You haven;t changed the Port to 7545. Please check , i face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to compile the contract before deploying. [Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdQZG.png)